# React-Native android build

Tags: react-native

im trying to generate an android build apk for a react-native app. When i run ./gradlew assembleDebug i get this error at executing
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Type io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/kmohammad/Desktop/Work/React-Native/Blazing-Grill/blazing-grills/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android/build/.transforms/ecf6c95930d8b11d8532da1d4d35dd90/transformed/classes/classes.dex, /Users/kmohammad/Desktop/Work/React-Native/Blazing-Grill/blazing-grills/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/build/.transforms/c524f9ff75507f0c8d7d8767447aed24/transformed/classes/classes.dex
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

I added multiDexEnabled true in my app/build.gradlew file and tried running ./gradlew clean multiple times.